# Iterating through lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops

I want to write code that will loop through a list and display only specific values.

I have code that looks like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(listt)) {
 list_sum = listt[[i]][1]
 summary(str_length(list_sum))
 list_sum
}
```

The rest of the code builds off of the value of list_sum. The code above works, but the list I'm working with has more than a 100,000 elements. How can I loop through so that I don't have to use '1' or '2' etc. to index.

Comment: There is no way not to iterate through. Unless you can turn it to a dataframe. Otherwise a short hard iteration could be wrapping it with `lapply`: `sapply(listt, "[[", 1)` or even `sapply(listt, getElement, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over lists can be done with `*apply()`-family commands; in this case, `lapply()` works.

```
listt <- lapply(1:1000, \(x) sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
lapply(listt, \(x) x[1])
```

[purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) furthermore provides `map()` and other functions for this.